# Haskell, HDBC.Sqlite3 - How to add a column if it doesn't exist already?

Tags: haskell, sqlite, hdbc

I have a function that given an `Int` returns a list of lists of Strings.

`fetchParts :: Int -> [[String]]`

This is what the output looks like

`[["title", "some title"], ["rate", "2.4"], ["dist", "some string"], ["tr", "1"], ["td, "2"] ..]]`

The length of the output can be variable. Only the first 3 lists can be present 100% of the time.

The later part of the list can be

`["a", "1"], ["b", "2"] ..`

or

`["some", "1"], ["part", "2"], ["of", "3"] ..]`

or

`["ex1", "a"], ["ex2", "b"], ..]`

or some other combination of strings.

And I want to add this output to a sqlite3 database file. I'm using [HDBC](https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.24/package/HDBC-2.4.0.2) and [HDBC.Sqlite3](https://www.stackage.org/package/HDBC-sqlite3) for this.

To add something to a database file I'm running functions like these

```
  initialConnection <- connectSqlite3 "src/parts.db"
  run initialConnection partsEntry []
  commit initialConnection
  disconnect initialConnection
```

where `partsEntry` is a simple SQL String like this

`partsEntry = "INSERT INTO PARTSDATA ( title, rate, dist, ...) VALUES ( "some title", "2.4", "some string", ...)`

where

`( title, rate, dist, ...)` are from `head <$> fetchParts 1`

and

`("some title", "2.4", "some string" ...)` are from `last <$> fetchParts 1`

The problem is say if `"some"` column doesn't exists, code will throw errors.

What I want to do is something like this

- if column `"abc"` doesn't exists, add column `"abc"` and insert
  `"this"` value at the current row
- if column `"abc"` exists, just insert `"this"` value at the current row

But I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.

First use `describeTable` function from HDBC package. The function will return column names and type. If you just need the names like I did, this is what you can do

```
getColumnsInTable :: conn -> String -> IO [String]
getColumnsInTable conn tableName = do
  d <- describeTable conn tableName
  return $ fst <$> d
```

The return will have all the columns' names.

Scan through the list to see if it contains all the columns you wish. If it doesn't use a function like the following to alter the table, i.e. add a new column with `INT` type.

```
createNewColumn conn columnName = do
  let stmt = "ALTER TABLE FantasyBooks ADD COLUMN " ++ columnName ++ " INT;"
  run conn stmt []
```